# Blender 4.0 Brightness Baking Dip

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I am feeding in a UV Texture to Blender 4.0.1 and baking it out for use elsewhere.
As I am testing, am just using a simple Plane, shrunk by 10% in the UVs, to give a wee border.
The UV texture is a pregenerated RG gradient in 32bit.
After the bake, I am noticing it is repeatedly maxing out it's brightness at 0.9683 instead of 1 on both R and G channels.

Anyone have any idea why Blender isn't baking out the full channel brightness?
(Being used as a map for veeeeery precise work, so can't be wrong, let alone 3.17% wrong)

Comment: Under _Render Properties_ > _Color Management_ do not use _View Transform_ > _Filmic_ or _AgX_, use _Standard_ instead and set the _Look_ to _None_.

Comment: I have used _View Transform_:**Raw** and _Look_:**None** already. This is what used to solve a gamma issue I had in the baking process.
Is there a major difference between **Raw** and **Standard** in _view transform_?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference, _Raw_ gives the image without **any** color space conversion, _Standard_ gives no **extra** conversion besides for the display (usually sRGB), which is gamma-corrected. So when _Standard_ is set to a _Gamma_ of 1, you have to set it to 2.2 to get the same image with _Raw_. Anyway, you say it is a UV texture. Now the question is, what do you need it for? Why so precise? For some calculation or just visuals? And how do you get the texture into Blender and where do you measure the values? Are you sure the texure has perfect 1.000 values? I get 0.9983 by the way

Comment: ..I'm just asking for the values, because when I save a file with perfect 100.00% Red and 100.00% from GIMP as an EXR and then re-open it in GIMP, I even have 0.2% Blue which should absolutely not be there at all. So I don't know if it is really only a problem with Blender here...

Comment: It's used as a base for some some UV remapping in After Effects, so need to be **very** precise.
To measure, I used the Info window in After Effects to check the before and after bake textures, then used the compare node (on isolated R and then G channels) in Blender Shading to highlight the maximum edge of the mesh (which was a plane to keep it simple while testing). This result corresponded with my AE results.
**EDIT** : should clarify in both Blender and AE, the final pixel measured at a value of 1 for the before and the after measured at 0.9683

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann - Thanks for your help, have managed to solve!
Turns out it was the Specular channel messing with me. I was using a Principle BSDF, switched for a Diffuse BSDF and all went away.
I guess we've just managed to avoid the Specular influence up to now by co-incidence.